# When I see the function definition with ALT+F12, what shortcut keys can close the pop-up window?

Tags: visual-studio-code

As shown below, how to use shortcut keys to close the pop-up window

https://i.stack.imgur.com/chQpO.png

Comment: You are required to post the minimal, relevant code that shows the problem here, not some third-party that can change or disappear helping no one. And no images either.

Comment: @Rob There is no code, just ask how to close the pop-up window. Images is a link https://i.stack.imgur.com/chQpO.png   should i ask such

Comment: @Rob Should i ask such question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'escape' will close it (same for most popup-like things in vscode).